# Apply styles to button on input text with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form maked with Bootstrap, i want to apply styles to button when the input text is focus (for example when focus background to green), how can i do?

Main structure:

```
  <div class="col-md-5"><div class="input-group">
        <input id="inputSearch cf" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JSFFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q3Le/

Comment: You can only have one ID per element. You have two on the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style in your site css file:

```
    .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #00cf00;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 207, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(0, 207, 0, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}

.form-control:focus + .input-group-btn .btn { background:green }
```

### [Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R5AJT/1/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q3Le/2/)

Try adding the below to your CSS:

```
input[id="inputSearch cf"]:focus{
    background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q3Le/1/

```
#inputSearch:focus {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}

#inputSearch:focus + .input-group-btn #btnSearch {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use jQuery.

```
$("[id='inputSearch cf']").click(function() {
        $("#btnSearch").css("backgroundColor","green");
 });
```

Of course before that you should load jQuery library

Here you can find a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q3Le/4/